# Error In Internationalize a GWT UIBinder page with Messages

Tags: gwt, uibinder

We are using GWT & GWTP with UiBinder and I want to use properties files for messages.
I have seen [GWT app with UiBinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064371/localization-of-gwt-app-built-with-uibinder-doesnt-work-in-hosted-mode) and [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287693/how-can-i-internationalize-a-gwt-uibinder-page-with-messages)  also.

1) Entries In gwt.xml file

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="en"/>   
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en"/>
```

2) In LoginView.ui.xml

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
xmlns:fmt="ui:with:com.nextenders.client.properties.NTCommonPropeties"
ui:generateFormat='com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.format.PropertiesFormat'
ui:generateKeys='com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.keygen.MD5KeyGenerator'
ui:generateLocales="en">
```

I have created a file and interface and added in Xml.

```
<ui:with field='fmt' type='com.nextenders.client.properties.LocalizableResource'/>
```

Now I am trying to use

Now I am trying to compile with "-extra" option.
But I am getting "`No resource found for key`" error.

In which order need to go through all the steps described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064371/localization-of-gwt-app-built-with-uibinder-doesnt-work-in-hosted-mode)
I mean Should I set messages after compile.

UPDATE: I have removed
`<g:Label text="{fmt.loginBoxTitle}" styleName= "login_label" />`. But Still It give same error when I compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. The error `"No resource found for key` means GWT compiler is not able to find mapping for the key you have specified. E.g. `loginBoxTitle` in my `{fmt.loginBoxTitle}`

I have rechecked files for mappings. It worked.